# Storing data in a RecordSet

Tags: java, maven, recordset

I am writing a code to record data which will also allow me to check and see if the data is updated to the records. I have imported the javaxt.sql.Recordset as a dependencies which allow me to use the Recordset constructors.

I want to place information in a RecordSet by updating the record.

```
    RecordSet rs = new RecordSet();     
    String db = null;//String name;

    rs.addNew();
    rs.setValue("Joe");
    rs.setValue("Brown");
    rs.setValue(25);
    rs.update();
    rs.close();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RecordSet is a partially sql wrapper, so you need to know sql.
Examples, how use RecordSet:
http://www.javaxt.com/javaxt-core/sql/Recordset